# How to read and save *.doc file in Java Programatically?

Tags: java

I am developing a online Content Management site.In which I want to allow user to upload their articles via a doc file.so, now i want to read text from that text file and if user want they can save their articles to a doc file.so, kindly tell me which API to use for this functionalities.It is preferred to have free API.but all suggestions are welcomed.

Thank YOU.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're probably looking for POI

See http://poi.apache.org/

EDIT: specifically you want http://poi.apache.org/hwpf/index.html (the word document portion of the project)